# Dealer mistake in a cash game?

Tags: rules, muck

Villian bluffs all-in on the river. Hero snap calls and Villian immediately mucks their cards in disgust. Hero reveals Ace high. Dealer turns over Villian's mucked cards, revealing bottom pair and ships them the pot.

Hero argues that Villian mucked their cards, so the Dealer should not have flipped them over. Isn't Villian's hand dead once they mucked, and Hero should take the pot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost every rule set, once you are all in, you are committed through every other street and thus on the immediate moment that a showdown happens, your hand is forced to be opened and you have no choice (or timing) to option-fold after your all-in, so the dealer would be making the right decision based on the rules. HOWEVER, Hero's argument does have a point - while the rules does not give the Villian the chance (or rights) to forfeit their hand, the Villian does have responsibility in upkeeping their forfeiture, especially the effect it has on other players. It would not be against reason to issue the pot against the rules just to disqualify him, however that would not be upon the basis of the rules.